# How to send an empty tag in a webservice

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [web service request call SOAP request missing empty parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951322/web-service-request-call-soap-request-missing-empty-parameters)

I'm trying to call a webservice hosted by a third party. The XSD they've provided me with defines an element:

```
<xsd:element name="ElementName" type="String"/>
```

They have given me instructions that this element must not be populated but it must be included as an empty tag in the XML request

`<ElementName />`

I used wscf to generate an object from the schema and ElementName came out like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName="ElementName")]
    public string ElementName;
```

My problem is that when I generate XML request the tag is excluded in the generated XML rather than being an empty tag.

Is there perhaps some attribute I can add to the element to ensure that it gets sent through empty? How can I ensure it's included?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to assign the ElementName an empty string:

```
ElementName = string.Empty;
```